# React redirect using react-router-dom not working

Tags: reactjs

I want to redirect to home page after ajax response I used Redirect but not working

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    data: {req: data2},
    url: baseUrl+'sentOtp',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === "success") {
            return <Redirect to="/" />;
        }
    }
});
```

**Route.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/pdeals/:BrandName/all/:Type" component={BrowseFeedDeals} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Register} />
  </Switch>
</Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I used react-router-dom with updated version.but it doesn't redirect me to the home page and no errors in console

Comment: You can only use `<Redirect />` inside render methods. If you want to programmatically redirect, you'll have to use `this.props.history.push`. Note that for the history object to be available in your props, your component must either be Routed to, or be wrapped inside a `withRouter` HOC.

Comment: Yes. But I haven't any idea about how to modify my route js file. please edit my route js file

Comment: It's not your route.js file that needs to be modified, it's your ajax handler (and the component where it's located). And I've told you what needs to be done, go ahead and try it on your own, then update your code if you still can not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use history.push. See my example below:

**index.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { render } from 'react-dom'
    import { Router, Route, BrowserHistory as hashHistory, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
    import './style.css'
    import history from './history.js'

    import Home from './routes/home.js'

    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        )
      }
    }

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**history.js**

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
export default createHistory()
```

**Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import history from '../../history.js'


export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

  linkClick() {
    history.push('/')
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.linkClick}>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: where can i find history.js file

Comment: There are only 2 lines in history.js, please see my code above. You can  create it separately.

Comment: here i need to install history from npm